# How to pass large amount of data from parent LWC to Child LWC?

Tags: community

This is my child Lightning Web Component that is being called from parent LWC.
I am passing many parameters to child LWC. Is this the efficient way to pass data or is there any other way ?

```
<c-call-Connected 
        title={titleForCallConnected} displayfieldone={displayFieldOneForCallConnected}
        displayfieldtwo={displayFieldTwoForCallConnected} recordid={recordIdForCallConnected}
        titlefield={titleField} diallednumber={toPhoneForCallConnected} 
        objectname={objectNameForCallConnected}iconname={iconNameForCallConnected} 
        onendthecall={handleEndCall}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even create an `Object` with all these params as property in your parent component and then desterilize it and pass it as a single string. Just keep the `functions` aside to make thigs clearer, rest data can be serialized.

For eg :

```
<c-call-Connected 
    dataToBeShown={deserilizedObject}></c-call-Connected>
```

And then in your child component just parse and then assign the respective value to the attribute.

Not sure if its efficient but the advantage is that if the parameters to be pass increases, you just have to add that in the Object property, no need to keep on adding attributes to markup.